# "not exist" does not display results?

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT a.samAccountName
FROM   activeIds AS a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   #tmp1 AS b
                   WHERE  a.samAccountName = b.userID)
       AND a.samAccountName LIKE 'ysp%'
ORDER  BY a.samAccountName ASC;  
GO
```

I created a temp table that populates User IDs YSP0000 to YSP9999. 
I have an existing table (activeIds) that is already populated with YSP IDs.

I'm trying to output YSP IDs that DON'T exist in the existing table (activeIds) already.

For some reason the YSP IDs are not displaying and other IDs (for example ZSP) appear instead.

Is there a way to make the IDs appear?

Comment: Don't see how `zsp` can appear here. Your `WHERE ... LIKE 'ysp%'` should prevent that. Please provide some example data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I just decided to switch the table around in the code (ex. switch #tmp1 and samAccountName in all places, same with the columns) and it displays all the IDs not used. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is not `NOT EXISTS`, but `NOT IN`.  Something like this:

```
select samAccountName
from activeIds
where samAccountId not in
(
    select badAccountIds
    from #temp1
)
```

That will select all account names that IDs are not in the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the same thing with a `left outer join`.

```
select a.samAccountName
from activeIds a
   left outer join #tmp1 b on a.samAccountName = b.userID 
where b.userID is null  -- don't exist in #tmp1
      and a.samAccountName like 'ysp%'
order by a.samAccountName
```